# Many sites taking orders; one PayPal account

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal

I have setup and have been accepting orders on my main website using PayPal using IPN/Express Checkout. But I have 4 other, completely separate websites and I need to process orders using PayPal on them, too. Buy we're only allowed to have 1 PayPal account.

How can we accept PayPal payments on more than 1 website? I found 1 other question like this but it turned out not to be like this at all really. Is it really as simple as just specifying the different IPN urls/return urls in the Buy Now button form code for each website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really as simple as just specifying the different IPN
>   urls/return urls in the Buy Now button form code for each website?

Answer is ***YES***.

You just need to set different ReturnURL and CancelURL for each site, so that PayPal can redirect back to original site.

The rest of the options are same for all 4 sites.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer. I just wasn't sure it we could do it and if it was allowed.